# Easily differentiate video files from image files in Node

Tags: node.js, html, image, video

I'm building a project where people can upload files, I would like to then display those files in a browser where people can interact with them (vote, comment etc)

However, this means I need to programatically build the html depending on the format of the video or image. Is there a way to feed a file (or filename) into a library, and determine whether I need to display it in a video element or an image element? Even a list of video formats vs image formats would help but I haven't seen anything in regards to that.

Comment: You're opening a pretty big topic trying to look at all video formats... and support is different depending on browser, etc. But images are easier. Off the top of my head, image extensions: `jpg`/`jpeg`, `png`, `gif`, `svg` would be the vast majority.

Comment: Also, if you upload using an `input type="file"`, you can filter which filetypes it will choose... more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No module can reliably determine the file type. The **user** could either change the **extension** or even the **magic number** of the file to obfuscate it. The only reliable way it to try to pass file to some image / video transcoder to let it decide or error out if the format is invalid. This way you know you are working with known formats since all files are transcoded to your specific extensions. That could be mp4 or png. I recommend using `handbrake` for videos and `sharp` for images. Leaving the NPM links down below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/handbrake-js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Comment: Thanks. Is there a definitive list of image/audio/video formats? Or perhaps a list of just the most used?

Comment: Not an expert of all available codecs/extensions sadly. I have used this technique described above for a project and it worked fine. I pass the file uploaded directly to the transcoder and if it errors I just return an error back to the front-end to my webpage ( unsupported file format ).

Comment: This way I leave it to the sharp module developers to try and convert the images to PNG and resize them for my web app and if the file is not supported, is up to them. Something similar should happen to your videos too. You don't want to serve users with 10 different file types to watch on the browser. The server should have specific codecs to store files.